# Timer API linux

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am learning about timers in Linux.
I have the written the following basic module for Timers:

```
#include<linux/module.h>
#include<linux/kernel.h>
#include<linux/init.h>
#include<linux/timer.h>

static struct timer_list my_timer;
void my_time_callback(unsigned long data)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "%s has data %ld with %ld",__FUNCTION__,data,jiffies);

}
static int __init my_init(void)
{
    int ret;
    printk(KERN_INFO "Timer module is loading\n");
    setup_timer(&my_timer,my_time_callback,1);
    ret=mod_timer(&my_timer,jiffies+msecs_to_jiffies(1000));//1000 milli-seocnd in the future
    if(ret) 
        printk(KERN_INFO "Error in loading Timer module\n");

    return 0;

}
static void __exit my_exit(void)
{
    int ret;
    ret=del_timer_sync(&my_timer);
    if(ret) 
        printk(KERN_INFO "Timer module is still in use\n");

    printk(KERN_INFO "Timer  module uninstalling\n");
    return; 

}

module_init(my_init);
module_exit(my_exit);

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

There is no issue regarding the compilation.
The problem is with **my_time_callback**.
It doesn't gets called always as I have specified.

The following logs from dmesg:

```
[53647.566806] Timer module is loading
[53376.367286] my_time_callback has data 1 with 4308221577
[53657.602750] my_time_callback has data 1 with 4308291808<6>[53686.687330] Timer  module uninstalling
[53692.505214] Timer module is loading
```

Once I loaded the module ,**my_time_callback** gets called (but 2 times),then
I unloaded the module and loaded it again.But this time there is no call to **my_time_callback**.

Why is it so??

Comment: It is better to have every `printk` string to be newline-terminated. Otherwise it is possible to miss output in the kernel log.

Comment: Thanks its working now.
Any particular resource you would like to mention for Linux-kernel learning.??
LDD,Robert,Ceasti books are bit old.

Comment: @AmanKhan Check this out: https://bootlin.com/doc/training/linux-kernel/ . Also, Eudyptula was quite good, but it's finished now.

Comment: @SamProtsenko Thanks man.